# MEAN.io animate Angular UI Collapse

Tags: angularjs, mean.io

I've been playing around with the bootstrap Collapse (angular UI implementation) to show and hide a well in a MEAN.io application. The show and hide code below works but it doesn't animate the transition between the two states. I'd like to get a smooth animated transition but so far everything I've tried hasn't worked. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
<hr>
<div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the dependency to `ngAnimate` in your Angular application:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Remember to load the corresponding JavaScript as well:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer you were right...Just in case anyone else is playing around with the MEAN.io. You need to use Bower to install angular-animate which for some reason isn't installed by default. Then you must include the following in config>assets.json       "bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js". Finally you use pass in the dependency as is said above. Thanks